# AdoNetAppender stops working after changes are made

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, adonetappender

I'm using log4net and I configured my XML file to log into database with AdoNetAppender and everything seems to work properly when I create the application and configure everything. And I can successfully log to the database. But when I change the message in my code then it stops logging to the database.

Here is my configuration:

```xml
<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="0" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="Server=USER-PC;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=mydb;Trusted_Connection=true;"/>
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log1 ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <converter>
        <name value="hex_thread" />
        <type value="MyWebApplication.HexPatternConverter" />
      </converter>
      <conversionPattern value="%hex_thread" />
    </layout>
    </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="50"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="2000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

I found it online and did a little modification to suit my application. I'm thinking it could be because we insert into the table Log1 before getting the parameters MAYBE I really don't know because I am new to XML world and I know very little about it.

If my code is

```
 private static readonly ILog dblog = LogManager.GetLogger("ADONetAppender");
 dblog.Info("logging to db");
```

it works the first time, and then I change the message like this

```
dblog.Info("I AM LOGGING TO DB"); 
dblog.Info("me again");
```

it will not work at all, my file appenders are all right they can take the message change but my AdoNetAppender refuses this. Why is this happening?

**Edited to add:**

My functions are very simple I have this class to do the logging:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; using System.Web;using log4net; 
using log4net.Config; using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Layout; using System.Text; 
using System.IO; 
using log4net.Layout.Pattern; 

namespace myWebApplication 
{

public sealed class HexPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    override protected void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        long id;
        if (long.TryParse(loggingEvent.ThreadName, out id))
        {
            writer.Write(id.ToString("X"));
        }
        else
        {
            writer.Write(loggingEvent.ThreadName);
        }
    }
}

public class myClass
{
    private static readonly ILog secondlog = LogManager.GetLogger("methodB");
    private static readonly ILog thirdlog = LogManager.GetLogger("methodC");
    private static readonly ILog fourthlog = LogManager.GetLogger("methodD");
    private static readonly ILog fifthlog = LogManager.GetLogger("ADONetAppender");

    public static int methodA()
    {
        int a = 0;
        return a;
    }
    public static void methodB()
    {
        methodA();
        secondlog.Info("inside method B");
    }
    public static void methodC()
    {
        methodB();
        thirdlog.Info("inside method C");
    }

    public static void methodD()
    {
        methodC();
        fourthlog.Info("inside D");
        fifthlog.Info("this is db log");
        fifthlog.Info("this is me logging to the db");
    }
}

}
```

The file logs are okay whenever I make changes but my DB log isn't writing to the database, because when I try to retrieve the data in my table there are no changes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My Logger Configuration

```xml
<logger name="ADONetAppender">
<appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender"/>
</logger>
<logger name="methodB">
  <appender-ref ref="methodB"/>
</logger>
<logger name="methodC">
  <appender-ref ref="methodC"/>
</logger>
<logger name="methodD">
  <appender-ref ref="methodD"/>
</logger>
<root>     
</root>
```

The last three are `RollingFileAppender`s and they work perfectly wether I change the message or I add a few other messages. It's the DB that's giving me headache when I change the message or I add a few more messages to log.

Comment: how do you configure the loggers in your configuration?

Comment: I just edited to add the loggers... please see.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOH finally, its worked well... There is some code that I included in my global.asax that shouldnt be there i believe. I just tried revoming  the code and it worked well. Now its instantly writing no matter how many changes i make.

Here is the code i have no idea what it does but i just found it online. It wasnt needed in my case

```
 log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy hier = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository() as log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy;

        if (hier != null)
        {
            //get ADONetAppender
            log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender adoAppender =
              (log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender)hier.GetLogger("ADONetAppender",
                hier.LoggerFactory).GetAppender("ADONetAppender");
            if (adoAppender != null)
            {
                adoAppender.ConnectionString =
                  System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
                adoAppender.ActivateOptions(); //refresh settings of appender
            }

        }
```

And after i removed it Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

First: change the buffer size to 1, not 0.

Second: if the first log message is working, your config file is fine. It's probably in the rest of your code, show us a little more.

If it's complicated, test with a very simple function or two then let us know what happens.

**Edited to add**

Okay, I see your code, and now I see that `HexPatternConverter` is being used to format one column: so something's probably going wrong there, such as throwing an exception. I suggest you try running this without using that class (just writing the Thread column as a plain string) and see if that changes anything.

Also, just in case you didn't know: if log4net encounters a SQL problem, it will fail silently. That seems unlikely in this case, because it's writing at least a couple of records, but still.

**Edited to add**

When you change the config file, IIS reloads the whole application, so maybe you're running out of resources. Do you have *other* database activity? Does it stop as well? Is it possible you're opening db connections and forgetting to close them? That would cause db activity to fail until the app restarts.

**Edited to add**

The ConnectionString in the config file doesn't open connections, it's just a place your program (or in this case log4net) knows to look. If you're not doing any DB activity besides log4net then it's probably not a connection problem.

Next thing to try: does log4net have this problem with a text file Appender?

Comment: check out i copied my class code. I posted as an answer coz i didnt know how to add the code to the comment. plz check for me!

Comment: I moved your code up into the question--you do that by clicking "edit". See my response, too.

Comment: that class does conversion of the threadID to hexdecimal. But its not part of the question coz its working okay. I just included to show the whole code. Maybe if its even code arrangement mistakenly.

Comment: It's working okay when `log.Info` *works* ; you don't know if it's working okay when `log.Info` *fails* .

Comment: no i dont know that. besides now whenever i make changes to the code and add few lines of code it will not respond but when i change the buffer size maybe to 1 one time and the next to 0 it will come back and show the other messages that logged in the database. I jst googled and found out the buffer holds the data before its written maybe that is where the problem lies. 
I just keep changing the buffer when it doesnt log to the database but i wish i could understand why do i need to keep changing the config file.

Comment: Thankz for giving me your time to answer my question. 
I removed the conversion class and i changed back to normal thread. But the problem persists when changes are made to the code i need to change the buffer size to get it logged in the database. I have no idea why

Comment: i dont have other database activity, but i'm not sure i closed the connections. i know i opened them in the configuration connectionString but how do i close them?

Comment: No my file appender is working perfectly no matter how many changes I make. I noticed somebody had the same problem while searching through stackoverflow questions but they failed to post the solution. I am still having the same problem but when i make changes to the buffer size i noticed the messages are shown in the database even the ones i thought they werent written to the database. any changes in the code will cause delay in writing to the database. what gives?